# Memento pattern: saving memento

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

There is one problem about this pattern that troubles me.

In a situation when we have to save a state into a file, is it class Memento that should be responsible for handling this process? (for example, providing SaveToFile and RestoreFromFile functions)

Comment: What other class would be reasonable to access the internal state of the Memento to either serialize or deserialize it?

Comment: The Originator class also has access to the internal state. In C# if I put [Serializable] to the Memento class, any other class in the world would be able to save and restore it. That is why I am a bit confused about which way is preferrable.

Comment: Could you put a bit more of your design into the question so that we can better understand the problem you are having?  Me, from a Java world, would have the serialization entirely within the class and avoid exposing the internal state at all. That said, that's me from a Java perspective. The way things work in C# may have some differences that lead me to not completely understanding why this is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

Long answer:

Think back to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). An object (or method, or module) should only have one *reason* to exist. That reason may be large or small, but it is *cohesive*. A [memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) exists to *manage temporal state*. In other words, track state as it changes, to allow moving backward and forward through those states. The goal of the memento pattern is essentially to enable chaining undo/redo (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) operations.

Those mementos may be serializable and the originator may also be serializable. Those serialized forms may be suitable for saving to disk, memory buffer, printing on paper, whatever you want: but the memento itself is not concerned with saving anything to disk. That is not its *responsibility*.

---

While an object may know how to serialize and deserialize itself<sup>1</sup>, generally the action of actually saving or loading to/from disk or anything else is the responsibility of another object. That is the idea behind "serialization": it is a *very* broad interface between any object that has a potential need to copy itself to another location, and objects responsible for communicating with those locations.

This is typically done with streams. Serialization really just means "convert this object into a string of bytes or characters" which a stream can then consume. The stream could be a file stream for saving/loading to/from a file on disk, the network, etc. It could be backed by a socket, HTTP, a web service, anything. The memento does not need to know what a "disk" is or what a "file" is.

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>While it may be appropriate for a simple object or a single object to manage its own serialization, a complex object or a module with a lot of objects (e.g. a group of [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)s) may be better served with objects that manage serialization for them. There is overhead associated with this, and it only makes sense to spend the time and effort when it makes the system design clearer.</sub></sup>